# Node module imported via require has no methods

Tags: node-modules

I'm having a problem with node modules that I cannot resolve. I have the following three files. I've included the basic methods of interest but have excluded the rest of the methods and the actual guts of the methods.

The problem that I'm struggling with is that when the publish_event method is called on the event_queue object from events.js node crashes with the following error:

*FATAL* TypeError: Object # has no method 'publish_event', stack:
TypeError: Object # has no method 'publish_event'
    at Events.publish_event (/Users/mburbidg/stormcloud/ccapi/cloud_pipes/node_modules/f5/server/services/event/events.js:137:15)

I cannot figure this out, you can see that I can use methods of the EventQueue object from index.js, another module, in our system just fine. I've checked names other obvious things several times.

Any suggestions as to how to proceed?

File 1 - f5/server/notifications/sqs_event_queue.js

---

```
function EventQueue() {
  this.queue_name = 'notification_queue';
  this.queue_url = null;
  this.sqs = null;
}

EventQueue.prototype.publish_event = function(event_data, registration_id, log, callback) {
...
}

EventQueue.prototype.start = function(callback) {
...
}


module.exports = new EventQueue();
```

---

File 2 - f5/server/index.js

---

```
var event_queue = require('f5/server/notifications/sqs_event_queue');

var start_notifications = function()
{
  event_queue.start(on_start);

  function on_start(error)
  {
  }
}
```

---

File 3 - f5/server/services/event/events.js

---

```
var event_queue = require('f5/server/notifications/sqs_event_queue');

function Events () {

}

Events.prototype.publish_event = function(event_data, registration_id, log, callback) {
  event_queue.publish_event(event_data, registration_id, log, callback);
};

module.exports = new Events();
```

---